# How often can I give my dog treats?

Tags: treats

What percentage of a dog diet should be treats?

I want to know how many treats should I be giving my dog without over feeding him.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as written. Treats come in all shapes and sizes. You can give your dog quite a few pieces of carrot as treats, without overfeeding him. If you're feeding a high fat treat, then the answer (as you probably know) is they should be given very sparingly.

Comment: I suspect that (and as an un-answered question, you have a little more freedom with finetuning) - its less about "how often" and "what percentage" than "when " and "what sort". There's probably a difference between my late dog's "furry grandkid" cheese treats, carrots or celery, and those small treats used for training.

Comment: @HarryV. I remember my vet saying treats should not consume a dog's diet by more than 10%. Wondering if others have heard the same. I think this question can in fact be answered.

Comment: Hey! I think what Harry and Journeyman are trying to get at is that refining your question somewhat to define what you mean by "treats" may get you a more useful answer. For example, Harry indicates that some dogs like carrots as treats - I'm guessing that a vet would say they could eat many more carrots than, say, packaged dog treats - which I think usually give directions for how many to feed based on dog weight on the packaging? I think if you have a specific type of treat you're interested in, that might be a narrower question to answer.

Comment: For an example - "I give my dog peanut butter as a treat and he really loves licking it out of Kong balls. He's a 20 pound dog. Is there a maximum amount of peanut butter I should give him in a day to avoid any intestinal distress? He doesn't have any general medical issues." Note, the number of treats may depend on the size of both the treat and the dog... a giant schnauzer may be able to go through quite a few more than a teacup terrier. :D